# Check validity of virtual memory address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I am iterating through the pages between VMALLOC_START and VMALLOC_END and I want to
check if the address that I get every time is valid.
How can I manage this?

I iterate through the pages like this:

```
unsigned long *p;

    for(p = (unsigned long *) VMALLOC_START; p <= (unsigned long *) (VMALLOC_END - PAGE_SIZE); p += PAGE_SIZE)
    {
            //How to check if p is OK to access it?     

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to try to red it, and catch the exception.

Catching the exception is done by defining an entry in the `__ex_table` secion, using inline assembly.
The exception table entry contains a pointer to a memory access instruction, and a pointer to a recovery address. If an segfault happens on this instruction, EIP will be set to the recovery address.

Something like this (I didn't test this, I may be missing something):

```
void *ptr=whatever;
int ok=1;
asm(
    "1: mov (%1),%1\n"    // Try to access
    "jmp 3f\n"            // Success - skip error handling
    "2: mov $0,%0\n"      // Error - set ok=0
    "3:\n"                // Jump here on success
    "\n.section __ex_table,\"a\""
    ".long 1b,2b\n"       // Use .quad for 64bit.
    ".prev\n"
    :"=r"(ok) : "r"(ptr)
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This solution is non portable, right? I am trying to manage this with pure C. For now I have this implementation but I think it's buggy:

https://github.com/PanosSakkos/shedder/blob/master/src/shedder_core.c#L44

Any ideas would be more than welcome :)
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a portable solution. I think your code also isn't portable. It also doesn't handle large pages (e.g. in x86, you can have a 2MB page, which means the pmd sometimes points directly to the physical address (or something like this).

Comment: Here http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?id=3&issue=61 (search for "problem of unmapped") it seems to illustrate a portable (in pure C) way to do it. I just can't understand it because it's terribly written. Thanks!

Comment: That code is not portable at all. Instead of using proper Linux macros, it uses hard coded constants (e.g. the page table is assumed to be always at 0xc0101000), and is good only for specific Linux versions, specific configurations and x86 only.

Comment: You are right, my bad for characterizing it as "portable" ^_^

I found this function: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L333

I think I should use this and if it returns a non present page, I should bring it to the VM, but how?
Also, if the page is too long (as you mentioned) what should I do?

Thanks!